# Laravel 5.3 modify LoginController response

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I want to modify response messages in Laravel 5.3 LoginController. As of now, when I try to login, it redirects me to login page with messages displayed at the top.

But instead of it, I want to use ajax notifications to display messages. 
How can I modify the logic for response in LoginController?

Sample code for ajax call I am currently using

```
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  url: 'http://mywebsite.com/login',
  success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
  }
});
```

**P.S** - I am a newbie to Laravel and this is my first app using the framework

Comment: Just to double check, are you using ajax to submit your login form?

Comment: @RossWilson: Yes I am using jQuery ajax to submit my form

Comment: provide your php script also

Comment: I haven't used any custom php script. It's the default LoginController in Laravel 5.3. I am a newbie to Laravel and this is my first app using the framework

Comment: so want you wanted is to know if your user credentials is correct or not? and display it using ajax? then if that you must create a php script for that using the laravel Auth

Comment: Yes. Keeping the original logic to detect user credentials same, I just want to extend the functionality to modify the user response. Is there any way to override the response functionality in Laravel 5.3?

Comment: Yes, you can create a script for that

Comment: How do I create script? What's to be done? Any custom guard has to be added? But I simply want to override the response logic

Comment: can I see your code inside the login Controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to override `sendLoginResponse()` and `sendFailedLoginResponse()` methods from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait so that you can check if the request is an ajax (or wants json).

In you `Auth/LoginController` add:

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'user' => $this->guard()->user(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ], 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}
```

This should allow you to keep to same `routes` for your project.

Also, if you add `dataType: 'json'` it should parse the response for you i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  url: 'http://mywebsite.com/login',
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'post',
  success:function(response){

        console.log('success', response);
  },
  error: function () {
      console.log('error', response)
  }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Thanks. Just for the note I have updated the `Request $request` passed in the functions to `$request`. Because you need to pass a new request object instead of results of Request::all() function.

Comment: What i was looking for, also works in the current version 5.7 whitout Request instance, only $request works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel Auth Component for that

first add this

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
```

then php action inside controller should be like this
use laravel Auth::attempt it checks if your user credentials is correct
and to be able it to read by javascript just display the result as json

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    $response = array();
    $conditions = array(
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password')
    );
    /* check if user credentials is okay */
    if (Auth::attempt($conditions)) {
        $response['message'] = 'Successfully login';
    } else {
        $response['message'] = 'Incorrect user credentials';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

And your ajax javascript function looks like this you must parse the ajax response to get it from javascript

```
$.ajax({
  data: data,
  url: 'http://mywebsite.com/login',
  success:function(response){
    response = JSON.parse(response); // parse your json data from ajax response your result like this {"message": "Successfully login"}
    console.log(response.message); // 
  }
});
```